# Move all files with a certain extension from multiple subdirectories into one directory

Tags: command-line, files, find, recursive

I have a bunch of .zip files in several directories:

```
Fol1/Fol2
Fol3
Fol4/Fol5
```

How would I do move them all to a common base folder?

Comment: Do you want to keep the directory structure? You want to move the directories, or just the zip files?

Comment: I just want to move the zip files. I don't really care about the directories - they can be left alone or deleted.

Comment: Have you not *"accepted"* an answer here because none of them addressed your question?

Answer (score 131):

Go to the toplevel directory of the tree containing the zip files (`cd …`), then run

```
mv **/*.zip /path/to/single/target/directory/
```

This works out of the box in zsh. If your shell is bash, you'll need to run `shopt -s globstar` first (you can and should put this command in your `~/.bashrc`). If your shell is ksh, you'll need to run `set -o globstar` first (put it in your `~/.kshrc`).

Alternatively, use `find`, which works everywhere with no special preparation but is more complicated:

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec mv {} /path/to/single/target/directory/ \;
```

If you want to remove empty directories afterwards, in zsh:

```
rmdir **/*(/^Fod)
```

In bash or ksh:

```
rmdir **/*/
```

and repeat as long as there are empty directories to remove. Alternatively, in any shell

```
find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Comment: First `find` command above worked in bash, but had to change to `find . -name` etc to get it to work.

Comment: @Jeff `.` is implicit for GNU find but not for others, I've added it explicitly.

Comment: WARNING If `directory` doesn't exist in `/path/to/single/target/`, the `mv` command will rename each file to `directory` and each one will overwrite the last, essentially deleting all your files.

Comment: @Alain Indeed. I've edited my answer to use `directory/` which causes an error if the directory doesn't exist or if it's a regular file.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - missed one though. The second command (using find) has the same problem. That's actually the one that bit me.

Comment: It looks like Globstar has been built into Bash since version 4.0 (released in 2009), so almost all modern OS's with Bash will have it out of the box.

Answer (score 23):

If you only want to move the `.zip` files, you could do something like

```
mkdir ./zipfiles
find . -name "*.zip" -exec mv "{}" ./zipfiles \;
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Simple and works if you have find. Another cool thing is if you want to move any kind of file you could use the type argument to find, such as: `find . type f -exec mv "{}" dest-dir \;`

Comment: find command also found moved files. `find . -path "./zipfiles" -prune -o -name "*.zip" -exec mv "{}" ./zipfiles \;` would avoid this, imo.

Answer (score 5):

This one is safe when moving data and error free which supported most of all distro regardless versions. This command will scan subdirectories and then move or copy to your new destination directory.

```
find . -name *.flac -exec mv '{}' "./flac/" ";"
```

- Run this command at the main directory that contains sub-directories with the files you wish to move.
- Where you can change `*.flac` to anything like `*.zip` in your case. Or `*.doc` just any extension works.
- and `mv` is the command to move files, or you can use `cp` to copy data instead of moving.
- `./flac/` is the destination directory that I want to move all FLAC files to.  You can also give it a full path like `/home/myid/flac/`

Full example. (in this case, there are many subdirectories with music artist name at `/home/myid/Music/` and then FLAC files are all over different subdirectories level.
Since I don't need artist folders but want to have all FLAC files into one directory at `/home/myid/Music/flac/`

```
cd /home/myid/Music
mkdir flac
find . -name *.flac -exec mv '{}' "./flac/" ";"
cd flac
ls
```

Then it will display all FLAC files.

Comment: what does `;` do?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi it make sure to wait until the bash command in the same line finish its job. and then move on to the next line of bash commands. This is useful for commands that contains scripts like .pl or python because bash will just run it and then jump to the next line, so to be safe, i use ; after the commands that takes time or script, in case bash skips it.

Comment: This is a not very useful repeat of previous answers but with FLAC added, which was not in the question

Comment: @brianlmerritt I mentioned "compatible" while other answers are not compatible, and the question mentioned "certain" extension so I can use any extension in example. read the question again. or have experience on multiple distro.

Comment: @brianlmerritt and there is the reason why 4 people found mine useful after trying previous answers, Try to tackle the other 3 answers that repeat as well if you have enough experience on bash and find out what will cause an error when it comes to multi distro.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using **bash** version 4 or higher or **zsh** you can also use recursive globbing:

```
mv **/*.zip /path/to/move/zip/files/to
```

This will move ONLY the files and not their relative paths, so collisions might occur.

Comment: what do you mean by relative paths?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the GNU versions of find and mv, the following will be more efficient than the existing find-based answers:

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec mv --target-directory='/path/to/outputdir' '{}' +
```

Using a `+` at the end of the find -exec means that a list of files will be passed to the mv command, rather than executing one mv command per file found. However, a limitation of this is that you can only place the '{}' at the end of the command, which necessitates the use of the mv --target-directory option, and as far as I know that's a GNU-ism.

Answer (score 0):

As a bash hack, you could use the power of `tar`:

```
(cd origin/;find . -exec file --mime-type "{}" \;|grep "application/zip"|cut -d ':' -f 1|xargs tar cf -)|(cd target/; tar xf -) && rm -fr origin/
```

This has the advantage that it does not depend on file extensions, since it uses the `file` command to choose the files to move and it preserves the directory structure, but it doesn't work with paths containing spaces.

The final `rm` is there just to remove the original files (becouse @InquilineKea tolds that he doesn't care about the original folder in the comment).

Of course this is particularly suitable if the origin/ and target/ folders are on different disks. Otherwise the other solutions proposed are more efficient (even if they rely on naming conventions, instead of `file`'s content).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gilles' advice where he suggested

```
mv **/*.zip /path/to/single/target/directory/
```

you may get feedback saying

```
mv: will not overwrite just-created
```

because there might be duplicate file names being copied to the target directory.

If you add `--backup=numbered` this will create numbered backup files with duplicate names.

e.g. `duplicate-name.zip.~1~`