# Transfering pdf files in hundreds of directories

Tags: file-transfer

I have hundreds of directories which contain a number of pdf files.   What command can I use to transfer the pdf files residing in these directories to some particular location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move all files with a certain extension from multiple subdirectories into one directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67503) see also [Move pdfs...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/730215/)

Comment: Found the find command for my problem.